# creating a new column based on groupby sum condition and groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this dataframe, I need to create a reached_det and reached_web column in Pandas dataframe.
The conditions for this is if sum of detail for any particular geo_id > 0, then reached_det for that id is 1. Similarly for reached web.

[image: I have this dataframe, I need to create a reached_det and reached_web column in Pandas dataframe. The conditions for this is if sum of detail for any particular geo_id > 0, then reached_det for that id is 1. Similarly for reached web.]

The Final data will look like this

[image]

Condition is shown below

[image]

My code in python. It is giving me error. Please help

```
data['reached_det'] =np.where(data.groupby('geo_id'])['det'].sum()>0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change it with `transform`

```
data['reached_det'] = np.where(data.groupby('geo_id'])['det'].transform('sum')>0, 1, 0)
```